# How to use renderer grid in magento2?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid, adminform, uielement

I've developed a custom module for magento1.9 , I'm doing the same for magento2 I'm able to have just a grid in admin page, also I have a form in admin page but I'm a bit stopped as I can't understand how to have both form and grid in the same page.
in my module1.9 I've used the renderer way to put a grid with form using this lines of codes

```
<?php
class Ns_Thorleif_Block_Adminhtml_Commerciaux_Edit_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Grid extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract{
    protected $_element;

    public function getElementHtml()
    {
        //return Mage::helper('core')->getLayout()->createBlock('blockname_node/adminhtml_payment_edit_form_renderer_fieldset_customer_grid')->toHtml();
        return Mage::helper('core')->getLayout()->createBlock('thorleif/adminhtml_commerciaux_grid')->toHtml();
    }
}
```